# Binary Tree Question

Tags: binary-trees

[image]

Using the diagram of a binary tree and algorithm answer the following:

If the following commands store(1,laurence), store(1, ron), store(1,graham), store(1,abe) and store(1,martin) are executed what will be stored at location (3)?

1. ron
2. abe
3. graham
4. empty

The answer is ron but I am struggling to work out why. How does the algorithm correspond to the tree? Thanks.

Comment: Don't use images as main content of your post. This makes your question impossible to search and inaccessible to the visually impaired; [we don't like that](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/752/should-we-do-anything-about-questions-that-are-just-a-scan-of-a-problem-in-their). Please transcribe text, mathematics, and algorithms (note that you can [use LaTeX](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands)) and don't forget to give proper attribution to your sources!

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science! The title you have chosen is not well suited to representing your question. Please take some time to improve it; we have collected some advice [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/815/). Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We start in `store(1,laurence)` and since `1` is empty, we simply put `laurence` in `1`.

We then go in `store(1,ron)` and see that `1` is not empty so we compare `ron` to the value of `1`: `laurence`, and since `laurence`$\not>$`ron`, we then go to `store(1.upper,ron)`. So since `1.upper`$=$`3`, we are now in `store(3,ron)`. Since `3` is empty, we simply put `ron` in `3`.

Now, since we always check that the spot is empty before settings its `data`, the `data` of `3` will never change. So at the end, it's still `ron`.

---

The tree is just here to tell you that `1.upper`$=$`3`.

But you can "run" the algorithm on this visual representation of the tree: Start at the leftmost node. If there's nothing written, write whatever you want to write, otherwise, depending on how what you want to write compares to what is written, either go up or down.

---

By the way, having "upper" pointing down and "lower" poiting up is really confusing...